# How to make jest mocked functions throw an error by default

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking

If I create a mock as follows using `jest-mock-extended`:

```
export interface SomeClient {
  someFunction(): number;
  someOtherFunction(): number;
}

const mockClient = mock<SomeClient>();

mockClient.someFunction.mockImplementation(() => 1);
```

Then functions on the mock will, by default, return `undefined` unless an explicit implementation is provided. So if you forget to specify a mock implementation, like for `someOtherFunction` above, you'll get `undefined` back.

```
mockClient.someFunction();      // returns 1
mockClient.someOtherFunction(); // returns undefined
```

While this will usually cause tests using the mock to fail anyway given the proper assertions, the root cause is often quite hard to find. The code under test might not be expecting undefined. It might throw an error immediately, or it might cause a problem further on. If using typescript, then the undefined value may not even match the expected types.

To highlight missing mocks earlier and more clearly, we could provide a default implementation for all functions, that throws an error:

```
const mockClient = mock<SomeClient>({
  someFunction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    throw new Error('someFunction not mocked');
  }),
  someOtherFunction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    throw new Error('someOtherFunction not mocked');
  }),
});
```

But doing this consistently will be tiresome when there are many functions, and require extending when new functions are added.

So my question is, is there a natural way to apply a *default* mock implementation to all functions using jest?

Comment: It's not clear. Can you show some code to explain your question?

Comment: Thanks, updated to hopefully make things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"jest-mock-extended": "^3.0.4"*

You can provide a `fallbackMockImplementation` for the `mock()` function. This feature was released at 3.0.2, see [PR#110](https://github.com/marchaos/jest-mock-extended/pull/110)

```
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';

interface SomeClient {
    someFunction(): number;
    someOtherFunction(): number;
}

test('throwing an error if we forget to specify the return value', () => {
    const mockClient = mock<SomeClient>(
        {},
        {
            fallbackMockImplementation: () => {
                throw new Error('not mocked');
            },
        },
    );
    expect(() => mockClient.someFunction()).toThrowError('not mocked');
    expect(() => mockClient.someOtherFunction()).toThrowError('not mocked');
});
```